# How to use nested forms with different relations using the cocoon gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, cocoon-gem

My dilemma has been around for a week now, I am trying to solve it but so far I have not been able to, so I am asking for help.

I have a Model Dealership and others nested (DealershipsSetting, Address, Machines, Operators, Cards) where the has_one relation only applies to DealershipsSetting, so the others are has_many.
I can only write some information in the database tables, when I call the build method for each model of the nested forms, for example:

```
  def new
    @dealership = Dealership.new
    @ dealership.build_dealerships_setting if @ dealership.dealerships_setting.blank?
    @ dealership.addresses.build if @ dealership.addresses.blank?
...
  end

  def edit
    @ dealership.build_dealerships_setting if @ dealership.dealerships_setting.blank?
    @ dealership.addresses.build if @ dealership.addresses.blank?
...
  end
```

I realize:

a) The first thing I notice in the log is that the forms are redirected several times. It makes sense since I'm forcing them to build through the builds call (at least that's what I understand about it). But this is not the default behavior when using the gem, I tested in another application just to know how to use the gem by following the documentation https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon

b) Due to the call of the build method, the forms come open (ready to receive the data), I do not know if it is the default behavior.

c) When I call Action New or Edit, I can not record more than one record (type, 2 addresses, 3 cards or N operators)

d) In the documentation I did not notice any call to the build method, I found in the searches to try to solve my problem, for example, https://share.atelie.software/rails-nested-attributes-com-has-many-42ecf6179871

e) If I remove the calls from the builds, following the examples available in the documentation, the fields appear hidden until you call through the link_to_add_association, but no data, from the nested forms, is saved.

When I set my dealerships_controller like this, I can't add any register in the database:

```
def new    
   @dealership = Dealership.new        
end
...
def create
   @dealership = Dealership.new(dealership_params)

   respond_to do |format|
     if @dealership.save
        format.html { redirect_to users_backend_dealerships_path, notice: 'Dealership was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @dealership }
     else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @dealership.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
     end
   end
 end
....

def dealership_params
  params.require(:dealership).permit(
:fantasy_name, :social_name, :cpf, :cnpj, :municipal_registration, :state_registration, :credit, :phone, :manager_email, :is_available, :credits_package_id, dealerships_setting_attributes: [:id, :credit_alert, :contract_validity, :franchise_for_rent, :due_date, :credit_value, :is_available, :_destroy],addresses_attributes: [:id, :place, :neighborhood, :cep, :state, :city, :is_available, :_destroy], machines_attributes: [:id, :name, :model, :serial_number, :mac_address, :calibration_counter, :is_available, :_destroy], operators_attributes: [:id, :name, :cpf, :card, :is_available, :_destroy ], cards_attributes: [:id, :serial, :category, :credit_package, :client, :machine, :operator, :is_available, :_destroy ])
end
```

Like this, I can add one register by model in the database.

dealerships_controller

```
class UsersBackend :: DealershipsController <UsersBackendController
  before_action: set_dealership, only: [: show,: edit,: update,: destroy]
  before_action: get_credit_packages, only: [: edit,: update,: new]
 
 def index
    @dealerships = Dealership.includes(:dealerships_setting, :addresses, :machines, :operators, :cards)
  end

  def show
  end

  def add_credits
  end

  def new
    @dealership = Dealership.new        
    @dealership.build_dealerships_setting if @dealership.dealerships_setting.blank?
    @dealership.addresses.build if @dealership.addresses.blank?
    @dealership.machines.build if @dealership.machines.blank?
    @dealership.operators.build if @dealership.operators.blank?
    @dealership.cards.build if @dealership.cards.blank?
  end

  def edit
    @dealership.build_dealerships_setting if @dealership.dealerships_setting.blank?
    @dealership.addresses.build if @dealership.addresses.blank?
    @dealership.machines.build if @dealership.machines.blank?
    @dealership.operators.build if @dealership.operators.blank?
    @dealership.cards.build if @dealership.cards.blank?
  end

  def create
    @dealership = Dealership.new(dealership_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @dealership.save
        format.html { redirect_to users_backend_dealerships_path, notice: 'Dealership was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @dealership }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @dealership.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @dealership.update(dealership_params)
        format.html { redirect_to users_backend_dealerships_path, notice: 'Dealership was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @dealership }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @dealership.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

def destroy
    @dealership.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to users_backend_dealerships_path, notice: 'Dealership was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private

    def set_dealership
      @dealership = Dealership.find(params[:id])
    end

    def dealership_params
      params.require(:dealership).permit(:fantasy_name, :social_name, :cpf, :cnpj, :municipal_registration, :state_registration, :credit, :phone, :manager_email, :is_available, :credits_package_id,
        dealerships_setting_attributes: [:id, :credit_alert, :contract_validity, :franchise_for_rent, :due_date, :credit_value, :is_available, :_destroy],
        addresses_attributes: [:id, :place, :neighborhood, :cep, :state, :city, :is_available, :_destroy],
        machines_attributes: [:id, :name, :model, :serial_number, :mac_address, :calibration_counter, :is_available, :_destroy], 
        operators_attributes: [:id, :name, :cpf, :card, :is_available, :_destroy ],
        cards_attributes: [:id, :serial, :category, :credit_package, :client, :machine, :operator, :is_available, :_destroy ]
        )
    end

    def get_credit_packages
      @credit_packages = CreditsPackage.where(media_owner: 0)
    end
end
```

model  dealership.rb

```
class Dealership < ApplicationRecord

  has_many :credits_packages

  has_one :dealerships_setting, dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: :dealership

  has_many :addresses, dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: :dealership
  has_many :machines, dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: :dealership
  has_many :operators, dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: :dealership
  has_many :cards, dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: :dealership


  accepts_nested_attributes_for :dealerships_setting, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :addresses, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :machines, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :operators, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :cards, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :users, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
end
```

model dealerships_setting

```
class DealershipsSetting < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :dealership, inverse_of: :dealerships_setting
end
```

model address.rb

```
class Address < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :dealership
end
```

form.html.erb (dealership)

```
<%= form_with(model: [ :users_backend, @dealership], local: true) do |form| %>
     <div class="form-group">
          <strong><%= form.label :fantasy_name %></strong>
               <%= form.text_field :fantasy_name, autofocus: true, class:"text-uppercase form-control", placeholder:t('place_holders.fantasy_name') %>
     </div>
...

<%= form.fields_for :dealerships_setting, @dealership.dealerships_setting do |dealerships_setting| %>
     <%= render partial: 'dealerships_setting_fields', locals: { f: dealerships_setting } %>
  <% end %>

<div id="addresses"> 
    <%= form.fields_for :addresses do |address| %> 
<%= render partial: 'address_fields', locals: { f: address } %>
    <% end %>
    <%= link_to_add_association('Add address', form, :addresses) %>
 </div> 
....others nested forms...
```

_dealerships_setting_fields.html.erb

```
<div class="nested-fields">
  <div class="form-group">
    <strong><%= f.label :contract_validity %></strong>
    <%= f.text_field :contract_validity, class:"form-control ", placeholder:t('place_holders.contract_validity') %>
  </div> ...another fields...
```

_address_fields.html.erb

```
<div class='nested-fields'>
  <div class='form-group'>
    <strong><%= f.label :place %></strong>
    <%= f.text_field :place, class:"text-uppercase form-control", placeholder:t('place_holders.place') %>
  </div> ...another fields...
```

What do I need?
A - Manage dealerships, where they must have one configuration and one or more addresses, machines, operators and cards.

I will be very grateful to anyone who can help me.

Comment: I know it's not helpful, but sometimes I find the nested attributes doesn't work. But only *sometimes*. So I create helper methods to loop through and create the associated records the long way. I keep with `fields_for` and all but sometimes, it just doesn't work for me :(

Comment: Many thanks @MikeHeft I'm still hopeful for a solution, I think it may exist. ;)

Comment: Please explain: if you say "add a register", do you mean saving a record? Could you show the logfile, the form redirections should not be caused by the "build" (it just pre-creates data), and the logfile hopefully show us some more information why the records would not be saved? I am curious how the params are posted, the strong params definition has to be matching correctly.

Comment: Hi, @nathanvda thanks a lot for help me.

Firstly I’d like to say that I’m a beginner on web development, I think is perceptible :)

So, I did a gist if you could check out, this is the link 

https://gist.github.com/jonaslucena/b7f44bd17d5b3f35705aa94633a1ef31

About your questions, sorry for my poor English, I’ll try answer better.

Yes I’m trying to say “save a new record”.
About the log file I just can send tomorrow, ok?

I appreciate your support, thanks a lot! Best regards

Comment: The code all looks fine to me (but it is a lot, so I could of course overlook errors). The only things I can think of: failing validations or strong parameters blocking parameters. I am looking forward to seeing the logfile. Otherwise if you have a github-repo that would reproduce this problem, I will take a look.

Comment: Hi @nathanvda, I shared a github-repo with you, thanks again!

Comment: You should check the your HTML: if a surrounding div of a form is closed, the form is also closed. You are using ERB, so this allows you to write incorrect HTML, but the browser will not always work equally wel. So move your form tag to the highest, containing surrounding level.

Comment: Was this clear for you?

Comment: Yes, thank so much for helping me, I understood that you said. I'll start to learn about slim, try to improve my code and try to minimize the mistakes that I did. Once again, thank very much!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so there were two main errors I encountered:

- your form tag was inside a div, but your form content spanned multiple divs. It will look correct but will not post the correct info in all cases
- secondly: you did have validations blocking the save, in my case, and then two things happened:

  - you did not set `@credit_packages` in your `create` action, giving an error when rerendering the form
  - you did not show any validation-error (so no feedback as to why the save failed)

So I did two things. In your `dealerships_controller` I edited the following line

```
before_action :get_credit_packages, only: [:edit, :update, :new, :create]
```

(also set credit packages on create)

And your `_form.html.erb` I moved the `form_with` directly under the `row` div, and added some rudimentary display of the validation errors. The `row` div was never closed. Your full form:

```
<!-- Page Heading -->
<h1 class="h3 mb-4 text-gray-800"><%= action_message %></h1>
<div class="row">
  <%= form_with(model: [ :users_backend, @dealership], local: true) do |form| %>

    <p>
      <%= @dealership.errors.messages.inspect %>
    </p>


    <div class="col-lg-6"> <!-- card Dealerships Information-->
      <div class="card border-left-danger shadow mb-4">
        <a href="#collapseCardDealershipInformation" class="d-block card-header py-3" data-toggle="collapse" role="button" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseCardDealershipInformation"><h6 class="m-0 font-weight-bold text-primary"><%= t('labels.dealership_information') %></h6></a>
        <div class="collapse show" id="collapseCardDealershipInformation"> <!-- card Content - Collapse -->
          <div class="card-body">
            <div class="form-group">
              <strong><%= form.label :fantasy_name %></strong>
              <%= form.text_field :fantasy_name, autofocus: true, class:"text-uppercase form-control", placeholder:t('place_holders.fantasy_name') %>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <strong><%= form.label :social_name %></strong>
              <%= form.text_field :social_name, class:"text-uppercase form-control", placeholder:t('place_holders.social_name') %>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group row">
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <strong><%= form.label :phone %></strong>
                <%= form.text_field :phone, class:"form-control", placeholder:t('place_holders.phone') %>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <strong><%= form.label :manager_email %></strong>
                <%= form.text_field :manager_email, class:"text-downcase form-control", placeholder:t('place_holders.manager_email') %>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group row">
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <strong><%= form.label :cpf %></strong>
                <%= form.text_field :cpf, class:"form-control", placeholder:t('place_holders.cpf') %>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <strong><%= form.label :cnpj %></strong>
                <%= form.text_field :cnpj, class:"form-control", placeholder:t('place_holders.cnpj') %>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group row">
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <strong><%= form.label :municipal_registration %></strong>
                <%= form.text_field :municipal_registration, class:"form-control form-control-user", placeholder:t('place_holders.municipal_registration') %>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <strong><%= form.label :state_registration %></strong>
                <%= form.text_field :state_registration, class:"form-control form-control-user", placeholder:t('place_holders.state_registration') %>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <strong><%= form.label :credits_package %></strong>
              <%= form.collection_select(:credits_package_id, @credit_packages, :id, :name, {:prompt => t('prompt.credits_package')}, { class:"form-control" }) %>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group custom-control custom-checkbox small ">
              <%= form.check_box :is_available, class:"custom-control-input" %>
              <%= form.label :is_available, class:"custom-control-label" %>
            </div>

          </div> <!-- .card-body-->
        </div><!-- . card Content - Collapse -->
      </div> <!-- .mb4-->
    </div> <!-- .Dealerships Information (lg-6) -->

    <div class="col-lg-6"> <!-- card Financial Settings -->
      <div class="card border-left-danger shadow mb-4">
        <a href="#collapseCardDealershipFinancialSettings" class="d-block card-header py-3" data-toggle="collapse" role="button" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseCardDealershipFinancialSettings"><h6 class="m-0 font-weight-bold text-primary"><%= t('labels.financial_settings') %></h6></a>
          <div class="collapse show" id="collapseCardDealershipFinancialSettings">
            <div class="card-body">
              <%= form.fields_for :dealerships_setting, @dealership.dealerships_setting do |dealerships_setting| %>
                <%= render partial: 'dealerships_setting_fields', locals: { f: dealerships_setting } %>
              <% end %>
            </div> <!--card-body -->
          </div> <!--collapse card dealership Financial settings -->
      </div><!--mb-4 -->
    </div> <!-- .Financial Settings (lg-6) -->

    <div class="col-lg-12"> <!-- card Addresses -->
      <div class="card border-left-danger shadow mb-4">
        <a href="#collapseCardAddressess" class="d-block card-header py-3" data-toggle="collapse" role="button" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseCardAddressess"><h6 class="m-0 font-weight-bold text-primary"><%= t('labels.addresses') %></h6></a>
          <div class="collapse show" id="collapseCardAddressess">
            <div class="card-body">
              <div id="addresses">
                <%= form.fields_for :addresses do |address| %>
                  <%= render partial: 'address_fields', locals: { f: address } %>
                <% end %>
                <%= link_to_add_association('Adicionar endereço', form, :addresses) %>
              </div> <!--  addresses -->
            </div> <!--card-body -->
          </div> <!--collapse card dealership Addressess -->
      </div> <!-- mb-4 -->
    </div>  <!--col-lg-12 -->

    <div class="col-lg-12"> <!-- card Machines-->
      <div class="card border-left-warning shadow mb-4">
        <a href="#collapseCardDealershipMachines" class="d-block card-header py-3" data-toggle="collapse" role="button" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseCardDealershipMachines"><h6 class="m-0 font-weight-bold text-primary"><%= t('labels.machines') %></h6></a>
          <div class="collapse show" id="collapseCardDealershipMachines">
            <div class="card-body">
              <div id="machines">
                <%= form.fields_for :machines do |machine| %>
                  <%= render partial: 'machine_fields', locals: { f: machine } %>
                <% end %>
                <%= link_to_add_association('Adicionar equipamento', form, :machines) %>
              </div> <!-- machines -->
            </div> <!--card-body -->
          </div> <!--collapse card machines -->
      </div><!--mb-4 -->
    </div>  <!--col-lg-12 -->

    <div class="col-lg-6"> <!-- card Operators-->
      <div class="card border-left-warning shadow mb-4">
        <a href="#collapseCardDealershipOperators" class="d-block card-header py-3" data-toggle="collapse" role="button" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseCardDealershipOperators"><h6 class="m-0 font-weight-bold text-primary"><%= t('labels.operators') %></h6></a>
          <div class="collapse show" id="collapseCardDealershipOperators">
            <div class="card-body">
              <div id="operators">
                <%= form.fields_for :operators do |operator| %>
                  <%= render partial: 'operator_fields', locals: { f: operator } %>
                <% end %>
                <%= link_to_add_association('Adicionar operador', form, :operators) %>
              </div> <!-- operators -->
            </div> <!--card-body -->
          </div> <!--collapse card dealership settings information -->
      </div><!--mb-4 -->
    </div>  <!--.Operators (lg-6) -->

    <div class="col-lg-6"> <!-- Card Cards =) -->
      <div class="card border-left-warning shadow mb-4">
        <a href="#collapseCardDealershipCards" class="d-block card-header py-3" data-toggle="collapse" role="button" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseCardDealershipCards"><h6 class="m-0 font-weight-bold text-primary"><%= t('labels.cards') %></h6></a>
        <div class="collapse show" id="collapseCardDealershipCards">
          <div class="card-body">
            <div id="cards">
              <%= form.fields_for :cards do |c| %>
                <%= render partial: 'card_fields', locals: { f: c } %>
              <% end %>
              <%= link_to_add_association('Adicionar cartão', form, :cards) %>
            </div> <!-- cards -->
          </div> <!--card-body -->
        </div> <!--collapse card dealership cards -->
      </div><!--mb-4 -->
    </div>  <!--.Cards -->

    <div class="actions">
      <div class="col-sm-4 mb-3 mb-sm-0 ">
        <%= form.submit t('buttons.save'), class:"btn btn-success btn-user"%>
      </div>
    </div> <!-- actions -->

  <% end %>
</div>
```

And then I was able to save a dealership. The layout is now broken for some reason I do not understand, but I will let you fix that (the css class does not behave how I expect it?).

Note: this is one of the reasons I prefer (or advice) to use a library like haml, slim, .. because your view-code will be easier to read/maintain and will be correct.

Comment: Many thanks for your help, I'll start to learn about slim and haml, thanks for advice too. 
Best regards o/